# Run batch file from Windows Task Scheduler regardless of user logged in

Tags: windows, batch-file, taskscheduler

I have a batch file which will copy certain folders from an absolute path over as a backup. I currently need to make it so every midnight the batch file will be executed - and that's during the time when no one is on the computer.

Currently I've set up the task in Windows Task Scheduler to Run whether the user is logged in or not, saving the administrator's password, set a trigger each day at midnight, and start the bat file in its specified location with the path to the folder (without quotation marks) as the working directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4"     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2016-10-12T12:47:13.4632673</Date>
    <Author>GROUP\ini</Author>
    <Description>Creates a backup of DemoTestTool daily</Description>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2016-10-18T00:00:00Z</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>DEMO-TEST-SQL\Administrator</UserId>
      <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>false</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>false</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>true</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT4H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
    <RestartOnFailure>
      <Interval>PT2H</Interval>
      <Count>3</Count>
    </RestartOnFailure>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>\\tsclient\T\Main\Demo- Test_Tool\Programdata\Backup\BackupSys.bat</Command>
      <WorkingDirectory>\\tsclient\T\Main\Demo-Test_Tool\Programdata\Backup</WorkingDirectory>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Here's the complete setup exported as XML - problem is that I can't simply assume that someone will be online to have the scheduled task run, as it's meant to run automatically when no one is using the system.

My problem is that while the task may be able to run when I manually run it (press the green run icon in the Task Scheduler), the task won't execute at the planned time, possibly due to the \tsclient\T drive not being available at the given time.

Is there any way I can access this drive when there aren't a dedicated user online on the computer?

[Network location of backup batch file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCuQF.png)

The task is configured for Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: I don't really see a defined question.  What do you need help with?

Comment: Read [Mysterious Network Client](http://serverfault.com/questions/299470/mysterious-network-client) thread. Why do you think that `\\tsclient\T\…` might be _always_ available?

Comment: Use UNC paths. Mapped drives, obsolete for over 20 years, are mapped per user token, so unlikely to be mapped for your script. Drives are mapped per user token so admins have two.